# Unable to retrieve POST data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a webpage that displays a table of information from a database, with each td having id&name with an incrementing number attached.

```
while ($x <= $master_rows) {
if (isset($_POST["delete".$x])) {
    echo "test1".$_POST["price".$x]." ";
    $master_foodlist_delete = "DELETE FROM assig2_foodlist WHERE name=".$_POST["name".$x]."";
    $master_foodlist_delete_result=$mysqli->query($master_foodlist_delete);
    header("Location: ./masterlist.php");
}
$x++;
}
```

And the corresponding HTML on the page (after being generated via php):

```
<form method="POST" name="master_submit_food">
<table id="master_foodlist">
    ...
    <tbody>
    <tr><td class="col1"><input class="col1" id="name1" name="name1" value="test" readonly=""></td>
    <td class="col2"><input class="col2" id="price1" name="price1" value="9.99"></td>
    <td class="col3"><input class="col3" id="lazenbys1" name="lazenbys1" type="checkbox" checked=""></td>
    <td class="col3"><input class="col3" id="theref1" name="theref1" type="checkbox" checked=""></td>
    <td class="col3"><input class="col3" id="tradetable1" name="tradetable1" type="checkbox" checked=""></td>
    <td class="col3"><input class="col3" id="thewalk1" name="thewalk1" type="checkbox" checked=""></td>
    <td class="col3"><input class="col3" id="thegrove1" name="thegrove1" type="checkbox" checked=""></td>
    <td class="col4"><input type="submit" class="col4" id="delete1" name="delete1" value="delete"></td></tr>
    ....
    </tbody></table>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Basically, I want to click delete, it gets the name of the item and deletes it from the database. I have a submit button to edit the entire table which also doesn't work currently, but its within the same form so I think the issues may be linked?

Comment: Comment your `header("Location: ./masterlist.php");`

Answer (score 1):

The redirect in the loop causes page change in the first DELETE query, moves this code after while:

```
while ($x <= $master_rows) {
    if (isset($_POST["delete".$x])) {
        echo "test1".$_POST["price".$x]." ";
        $master_foodlist_delete = "DELETE FROM assig2_foodlist WHERE name=".$_POST["name".$x]."";
        $master_foodlist_delete_result=$mysqli->query($master_foodlist_delete);
    }
    $x++;
}
header("Location: ./masterlist.php");
```